# Mvvmcross Visibility in fluent binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have got EditText with swiss binding (last line):

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(WebServiceEditVisible); Text EditTextWebServiceAdress" />
```

How can I write binding to Visibility plugin and to Text property using Fluent binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fluent binding equivalent to the Swiss binding you have implemented would be:

Resource file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/your_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Codebehind:

```
var myEditText = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.your_edit_text);
var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<YourView, YourViewModel>();

bindingSet.Bind(yourEditText).For(c => c.Text).To(vm => 
vm.EditTextWebServiceAdress);
bindingSet.Bind(yourEditText).For(c => c.Visibility).To(vm => 
vm.WebServiceEditVisible).WithConversion(new MvxVisibilityValueConverter());

bindingSet.Apply();
```

This code would go in the OnCreateView override of your fragment. If you're working inside an activity, it would go inside OnCreate instead, and you'd need to change `view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.your_edit_text);` to `FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.your_edit_text);`.